# Pagebreak destroys page layout

Tags: vertical-alignment, page-breaking

I have the following code to add an appendix to my document:

```
\appendix{}
\chapter{Questionnaire}
\pagebreak
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{questionnaire1.png}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{questionnaire2.png}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{questionnaire3.png}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{questionnaire4.png}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{questionnaire5.png}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{questionnaire6.png}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{questionnaire7.png}
```

The problem is, the linebreak is destroying my layout. The next pictures shows how it should look like

[image]

But unfortunately it looks like this
[image]

So I dont know why the pagebreak destroys the layout. Any hints?

Comment: It looks like you are using some custom chapter style, maybe this is a problem. Wouldn't \newpage instead of \pagebreak do the trick? Also, depending on the size of your pictures, you have to but an empty line between the \includegraphics commands to allow a break between the pictures

Comment: The word "site" in your question title confuses me.  Aren't you talking about *page* layout?

Comment: @Matthew: I guess "site" is inspired by the German "Seite", meaning "page".

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Yes that was the problem ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `\newpage` instead of `\pagebreak`, then a vertical formatting is ignored.
You can also insert a `\vfill` before `\newpage` to be sure, that an internally `\raggedbottom` has no effect.